# Can't get the selected value from a drop down menu

Tags: php

I have this piece of code in my PHP file to project the contents of a txt file as a drop down menu.

```
echo '<p style="text-align:center;"><form action="schedule.php" method="POST" name="theForm2" id="theForm2"></p>
    <p style="text-align:center;"><select name="fh[]"></p>';
    foreach($lines as $line) {
        echo '<option value="'. urlencode($line).'">'.$line.'</option>';
    }

echo '</select>
    <input type="submit" name="scheduleButton" value="Schedule" />
    <input type="submit" name="deleteButton" value="Delete"  />
    </form>';
```

And then i use this to get the selected value.

```
if (isset($_POST['deleteButton'])) {
   $v = ($_POST['deleteButton']);
}
```

But the problem is that every time i get v = "Delete".
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The name for a select element should not be an array. `<select name="fh">` On submit the drop down element selected will be in the `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `value` of the `deleteButton` control is "Delete". The code is doing exactly what you asked it to.

If you want the value of the `select` control, you need `$_POST["fh"]` and to change your select to `<select name="fh">`.